# GoogleSheet, Hot to subtract an array, each cell with the last one?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to find the time gap between a range of times, and ÷ was wondering if there is a way ÷ could do this with array formula?

A screenshot:

[image]

Here is how I do it now, I have a column with each row containing a time of day, what I do now is that I subtract each cell from the last to find the gap(duration) between times, but I need an array formula to do this with one code instead of having to write a simple subtract for who knows how many rows in a column, with the data I have

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,TEXT(A3:A1000-A2:A999, "[h]:mm:ss")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, doing the same.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"ELAPSED ";0;
    OFFSET($A$2,1,0,COUNT(A:A)-1)-OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNT(A:A)-1)})
```

This uses the the count of values up to the current row to calculate the appropriate offset from the first time, in A2, giving the two time values that are relevant for the current row.  Then one is subtracted from the other, to give the time delta.

[image]